# Why won't this if statement work?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa, if-statement

I have a button to change the `BOOL` `showSquare` equal to `YES`

This is the code for the button

```
- (IBAction)Tap_Square:(id)sender {
    [graphicsView setNeedsDisplay];
    [graphicsView setShowSquare:YES];
}
```

and this is where the if statement is

```
if (showSquare) {
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, white);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(90, 90, 100, 100));
}
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your property declared?

Comment: make sure `showSquare` is YES first and set breakpoint on `[graphicsView setShowSquare:YES]` to ensure it executed

Comment: the button is in ViewController.m while the if statement is in a subclass of a UIView (Called DrawView). The `BOOL` is declared in DrawView.h. Yes everything is imported correctly :)

Comment: @alpera YES is fine in Objective-C.

Comment: But how is it declared? As a property? Or an ivar?

Comment: OMG YES.. THANK YOU i got it working using the breakpoint !!

Comment: Where is the if statement located? I don't think you've shared enough code to be sure of an answer. Is it in update or somewhere else? Oh, also, since you're setting showSquare under graphicsView, perhaps you need to call graphicsView.showSquare?

Comment: Sorry i got it working, My `BOOL` was equal to NO, so i had to change the if statement to `if (_showSqaure)` for it to work !

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer below so we can get this off the unanswered list?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with properties instead of instance variables it is better to use accessor methods to get and set it's value.

```
// use self.showSquare if you call this code in graphicsView instance
if (self.showSquare) {
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, white);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(90, 90, 100, 100));
}
```

Also check if your property is synthesized or has getter and setter.

Comment: ... unless you are using XCode 4.4, in which case you nolonger need to synthesize your properties.

Answer (score 0):

graphicsView isn't nil?

Try setting a setter to showSquare, then debug it.